# Integration of CMake with the Visual Studio 2017 C++ Core Guidelines Checker (CppCoreCheck)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, static-code-analysis, cpp-core-guidelines

I currently try to integrate the [C++ Core Guidelines Checker (CppCoreCheck)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/code-quality/using-the-cpp-core-guidelines-checkers.md) of Visual Studio 2017 with the meta build system [CMake](https://cmake.org) using the `Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64` generator.

The following example illustrates my approach (I've tried to strip down the CMake source code to a minimum).

First I've added all compiler switches to the build target to analyze with CppCoreCheck:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(cppcorecheck-example)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED MODULE)

add_executable(app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE Boost::boost)
target_compile_options(app
    PRIVATE
    "/analyze"
    "/analyze:WX-"
    "/analyze:log" "cppcorecheck.xml"
    "/analyze:stacksize" 16384
    "/analyze:max_paths" 256
    "/analyze:ruleset" "CppCoreCheckRules.ruleset"
    "/analyze:plugin EspXEngine.dll"
    )
```

I'm using the following `main.cpp`:

```
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>

int main() {
  int arr[10];   // warning C26494
  int* p = arr;  // warning C26485

  {
    int* q = p + 1;  // warning C26481
    p = q++;         // warning C26481
  }
}
```

That example alone is sufficient to invoke CppCoreCheck during target compilation:

```
cmake -G"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -H. -B_build -DBOOST_ROOT="C:/boost-1.68.0-x64" -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON
cmake --build _build --target app
```

The following warnings are generated:

```
"c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj" (Standardziel) (1) ->
(ClCompile Ziel) -> 
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(237): warning C26440: Function 'boost::system::error_category::std_category::std_category' can be declared 'noexcept' (f.6: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=853927). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(244): warning C26412: Do not dereference an invalid pointer (lifetimes rule 1). 'return of name' was invalidated at line 243 by '(unknown)'.: Lines: 241, 243, 244 [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(319): warning C26432: If you define or delete any default operation in the type 'class boost::system::error_category', define or delete them all (c.21: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=853922). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(494): warning C26412: Do not dereference an invalid pointer (lifetimes rule 1). 'return of system_category' was invalidated at line 493 by '(unknown)'.: Lines: 491, 493, 494 [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(499): warning C26412: Do not dereference an invalid pointer (lifetimes rule 1). 'return of generic_category' was invalidated at line 498 by '(unknown)'.: Lines: 496, 498, 499 [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(763): warning C26490: Don't use reinterpret_cast (type.1: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=620417). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(753): warning C26440: Function 'boost::detail::throws' can be declared 'noexcept' (f.6: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=853927). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(768): warning C26412: Do not dereference an invalid pointer (lifetimes rule 1). 'return of throws' was invalidated at line 768 by '(unknown)'.: Lines: 767, 768 [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(824): warning C26472: Don't use a static_cast for arithmetic conversions. Use brace initialization, gsl::narrow_cast or gsl::narow (type.1: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=620417). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(825): warning C26490: Don't use reinterpret_cast (type.1: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=620417). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(822): warning C26440: Function 'boost::system::hash_value' can be declared 'noexcept' (f.6: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=853927). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(889): warning C26499: Could not find any lifetime tracking information for '*pc2': Lines: 896, 869, 872, 874, 875, 877, 878, 880, 881, 880, 883, 886, 887, 886, 889 [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(874): warning C26496: The variable 'bn' is assigned only once, mark it as const (con.4: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=784969). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(880): warning C26496: The variable 'bn' is assigned only once, mark it as const (con.4: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=784969). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(889): warning C26496: The variable 'bn' is assigned only once, mark it as const (con.4: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=784969). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(919): warning C26499: Could not find any lifetime tracking information for '*pc2': Lines: 930, 899, 902, 904, 905, 907, 908, 910, 911, 910, 913, 916, 917, 916, 919 [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(904): warning C26496: The variable 'bc' is assigned only once, mark it as const (con.4: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=784969). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(910): warning C26496: The variable 'bc' is assigned only once, mark it as const (con.4: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=784969). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68\boost\system\error_code.hpp(919): warning C26496: The variable 'bc' is assigned only once, mark it as const (con.4: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=784969). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\main.cpp(6): warning C26494: Variable 'arr' is uninitialized. Always initialize an object (type.5: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=620421). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\main.cpp(7): warning C26485: Expression 'arr': No array to pointer decay (bounds.3: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=620415). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\main.cpp(10): warning C26481: Don't use pointer arithmetic. Use span instead (bounds.1: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=620413). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\main.cpp(11): warning C26481: Don't use pointer arithmetic. Use span instead (bounds.1: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=620413). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]
  c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\main.cpp(5): warning C26440: Function 'main' can be declared 'noexcept' (f.6: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=853927). [c:\dev\cppcorecheck-example\_build\app.vcxproj]

    24 Warnung(en)
    0 Fehler

Verstrichene Zeit 00:00:05.77
```

In order to suppress the warnings form the third-party library *Boost* additional settings have to be provided.

Here's the catch: CppCoreCheck relies on **environment** variables for some parts of its configuration, more precisely:

- `Esp.Extensions`: Should be set to `CppCoreCheck.dll`
- `Esp.AnnotationBuildLevel`: Should be set to `ignore`
- `CAExcludePath`: Should be set to the directory paths to ignore (e.g. `C:\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68;C:\foo;`)

Is there any way to set environment variables for the compilation phase using CMake? I am currently not aware of an approach:

1. Setting environment variables as follows in the `CMakeLists.txt` does **not** work, since the environment variables are only valid during the configure phase:

   ```
   set(ENV{Esp.Extensions} "CppCoreCheck.dll")
   set(ENV{Esp.AnnotationBuildLevel} "ignore")
   set(ENV{CAExcludePath} "C:\\boost-1.68.0-x64\\include\\boost-1_68")
   ```
2. Using a custom command during the build phase of the target does not seem to work too:

   ```
   add_custom_command(TARGET ${args_TARGET}
     PRE_BUILD
     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/set_cppcorecheck.cmake"
     )
   ```

   Note: `set_cppcorecheck.cmake` contains the three `set` commands listed above.

It does properly work if the environment variables are set in the console invoking the build command, e.g.

```
SET Esp.Extensions=CppCoreCheck.dll
SET Esp.AnnotationBuildLevel=ignore
SET CAExcludePath=C:\dev\native\boost\boost-1.68.0-x64\include\boost-1_68

cmake --build _build --target app
```

But this is ugly and does not scale. Reason: My goal is to populate `CAExcludePath` automatically by the build system.

I've read https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/6u2myo/how_to_use_the_c_core_guidelines_checker_outside where the same problem has been described (without a solution).

Does anyone have a solution for my problem (setting an environment variable for the compilation phase of a "normal" target)?

Comment: I don't think this is possible (without resorting to extremely complicated measures like moving the whole invocation of all build commands inside a custom command), and I don't know of any other build tool that would require something like this. Imho this should be a feature request for the MSVC people: Make those options configurable from the command line.

Comment: Yeah, I thought a second about wrapping all the build related commands via `add_custom_command`, but discarded that thought very fast (that would be madness, imo). Thanks for your suggestion to provide a feature request. I will request that feature on https://visualstudio.uservoice.com and add a link to the request here later. Either CLI arguments or a configuration file would be much much better.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is not implemented yet. Also been searching for it. I think this should fix it: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/19682

I do see hints that maybe you can work around it with https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/customizing-your-environment-with-visual-c-and-open-folder/

Comment: Welcome to SO, even if links may answer the question, it is better to provide explanations. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for answering good practices